# How do leader skills interact with each other?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Let's say I have [Ra](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=496) as my leader and am using Ra as my helper from a friend too. Ra's Leader Skill is "Ray of the Sun" whose effect is "ATK x6 when attacking with Fire, Water, Wood, Light & Dark orb types at the same time." If I fulfill the criteria, would ATK become ×36 or is it additive? Do other leader skills work the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these leader skills are multiplied together will stack to be x36.  Two different leader skills affecting ATK will also multiply together.  (Ex: Byakko gives x3.5 multiplier.  Activating Byakko and Ra on the same combo gives 3.5 * 6 = x21)

Note that some ATK boost are based on attributes or creature types instead of the gems matched.  For example, Holy Dragon Indra gives x2 ATK to God and Dragon types.  This multiplier does not show up in the shiny numbers on the gem board, but if you instead watch the damamge numbers on the monster portrait, you can see that it actually is applied and does stack multiplicatively.

HP and defense multipliers stack this way as well.
Ex: Two leader skills that provide 50% resist (reducing damage taken to 1/2) will multiply together to provide 75% resist.  (damage taken is reduced to 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4)
Another example: 2 leader skills with x2 HP will result in x4 HP.

For a whole bunch of fun, bring two copies of Kushinada into a tri-color dungeon and try to hit the x100 multiplier.  (My best so far is x81)